# How do you get a resource's region in Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I have a Cognito user pool in Pulumi and I need to reference its region in another resource.
How does one get the region for a resource in Pulumi?

Answer (score 3):

The AWS provider doesn't allow defining the region per each resource. Instead, region is a property of the provider itself.

If you use the default ambient provider, then the region is in `aws.config.region`:

```typescript
const user = new aws.cognito.UserPool("up", { ... });

export const region = aws.config.region;
```

If you use an explicit provider, the region is defined by its options:

```js
const myProvider = new aws.Provider("my-provider", {
    region: "eu-north-1",
});

const user = new aws.cognito.UserPool("up", { ... }, { provider: myProvider });
```